# How to locate element from the nested frames

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to click id="C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC" under frame WorkAreaFrame1. But i was not able switch the frame. Getting error message as Unable to locate frame: WorkAreaFrame1. Pls do the needful.

I have opened a new window from parent window. In child window i need to click id="C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC" under frame WorkAreaFrame1. i was not able to clcik using below code.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("WorkAreaFrame1");
driver.findElement(By.id("C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC")).click();
```

**HTML Code**

```
<head></head>

<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows="42,*">

    <frame id="HeaderFrame" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" title="" name="HeaderFrame" src="/sap/bc/bsp/sap/crmcmp_hdr/bspwdapplication.do?></frame>
    <frameset id="contentFrameset" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="*,0">
        <frame id="WorkAreaFrame1"oaded('WorkAreaFrame1');" title="" name="WorkAreaFrame1" src="BSPWDApplication.do?crm-ext-integration=true&sap-client=300&…%2e00&sap-language=EN&sap-tray-padding=X&sap-tray-type=PLAIN" fsinit="loaded">
            #document
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html lang="en" style="height:100%;" webdriver="true">
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <script src="/sap(====)/bc/bsp/sap/gsbirp/biframecontroller.js?sap-client=300&sap-language=EN&sap-domainRelax=min" type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <div id="submitInProgress" class="th-sip" style="display:none;position:absolute;padding-top:15px;height:65px;"></div>
                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                        <form id="myFormId" action="/sap(bD1FTiZjPTMwMCZpPTEmZT1WMU5NVkVVeE1UQmZYMTlmTVRRMU56ZGZ…%2e00&sap-language=EN&sap-tray-padding=X&sap-tray-type=PLAIN" method="post" name="myFormId" target="WorkAreaFrame2">
                            <div id="htmlb_hidden_system_fields"></div>
                            <div style="display:none"></div>
                            <input id="wcf-secure-id" type="hidden" value="5C256D90A170A43A6866D59964334196" name="wcf-secure-id"></input>
                            <input id="thtmlbKeyboardFocusId" type="hidden" value="first_active_element_in_work_area" name="thtmlbKeyboardFocusId"></input>
                            <input id="thtmlbKeyboardSelectId" type="hidden" value="" name="thtmlbKeyboardSelectId"></input>
                            <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                            <div id="exceptionDisplayAreaDiv" class="th-msg-box" style="display:none;"></div>
                            <div id="rootAreaDiv" class="th-ajax-area">
                                <!--

                                 Begin rootAreaDiv 

                                -->
                                <script src="/sap(====)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_ui_start/crmuifClient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                <script src="/sap(====)/bc/bsp/sap/uicmp_ltx/LaunchTransaction.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
                                <div id="C1_W1_V2" tgt="" dhe="false">
                                    <!--

                                     Begin C1_W1_V2 

                                    -->
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr valign="top">
                                                                <td id="th_l_navcontainer" class="th-l-navcontainer">
                                                                    <div id="th_l_navTop"></div>
                                                                    <div id="C1_W1_V2_thescroll" class="th-sc-top" style="width: 172px; height: 344px;">
                                                                        <div id="C1_W1_V2_thescroll_scbox" class="th-sc-container" style="width: 172px; height: 344px;">
                                                                            <div id="C1_W1_V2_thescroll_sccontent" class="th-sc-content" style="width:172px;">
                                                                                <div id="C1_W1_V2_$navbar" class="th-ajax-area">
                                                                                    <!--

                                                                                     Begin C1_W1_V2_$navbar 

                                                                                    -->
                                                                                    <div id="C4_W14_V15" excevt="" intevt="c:C4_W14_V15:C1_W1_V2_C4_W14_V15_mainnavigationlinks.do;" automode="true" tgt="" dhe="true">
                                                                                        <!--

                                                                                         Begin C4_W14_V15 

                                                                                        -->
                                                                                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                                                                                        <div id="C1_W1_V2_C4_W14_V15_mainnavigationlinks.do" class="th-ajax-area">
                                                                                            <!--

                                                                                             Begin C1_W1_V2_C4_W14_V15_mainnavigationlinks.do 

                                                                                            -->
                                                                                            <ul id="C4_W14_V15_mainmenu" class="th-menu2" style="width:171px">
                                                                                                <li>
                                                                                                    <a id="C4_W14_V15_SLS-HOME" class="th-lk" oncontextmenu="return false;" onfocus="thtmlbSaveKeyboardFocus('C4_W14_V15_SLS-HOME');" title="Home" onclick="htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'thtmlb:link:click:0','myFormId','C4_W14_V15_SLS-HOME','SLS-HOM-WC',0);return false" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                                                                                </li>
                                                                                                <li class="th-menu2-sub-item">
                                                                                                    <a id="C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC" class="th-lk" oncontextmenu="return false;" onfocus="thtmlbSaveKeyboardFocus('C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC');" title="Account Management" onclick="htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'thtmlb:link:click:0','myFormId','C4_W14_V15_ZSLS-ACC','SLS-ACC-WC',0);return false" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                                                                                    <div class="th-menu2-arrow"></div>
                                                                                                    <ul class="th-menu2-sub"></ul>
                                                                                                </li>
                                                                                                <li class="th-menu2-sub-item">

Thanks Saravanan
```

Comment: Are you sure that id is not generated dynamically?

Comment: No olyv, Its not dynamic. I clciked one link in main window then this new window is opened. In that i was not able to do any action. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

According to the Javadocs, the defaultContent() method:

> Selects either the **first frame on the page**, or the main document when a page contains iframes.

This implies that it may be selecting the HeaderFrame in your document, whereas you just want to work with the main document.

Answer (score 0):

This might be 7 years late but I think this is Charm, no?

This is what I personally used to go through the frames and use inside elements [with recent technology :) ]

```
    var ifrm1 = document.getElementById('CRMApplicationFrame');
    var doc = ifrm1.contentDocument? 
           ifrm1.contentDocument: ifrm1.contentWindow.document;
    var ifrm2 = doc.getElementById('WorkAreaFrame1');
    var doc = ifrm2.contentDocument? 
           ifrm2.contentDocument: ifrm2.contentWindow.document;
    var area = doc.getElementById("thtmlbOverviewPageBox");
```

I would note that the ID you are looking for is a generated ID, which means it can change. you would want to look for it by using other attributes, or perhaps by using the closest Constant ID container and then querying a partial ID like so: [Element ID we're looking for : "C1_W1_V2_C1_W1_V2_V3_C26_W86_V88_aiccmcdoverview.do_0005" ]

```
    var trArea = area.querySelector("[id$='_aiccmcdoverview.do_0005']");
```